# nuxt spa is stuck on loading screen when deployed on CPanel while it works fine on local server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt project which was written by someone else. I built a production build by using `nuxt build --spa` and tested the build in `dist` folder locally b using PHP's built in server and it worked fine.

But after deploying to the CPanel hosting, it's just stuck on the loading screen and does not load. I'm new to Nuxt so I'm not sure what is the problem here. The url of the staging site is here http://staging.sustainabilityinnocenter.com. Please let me know what could be the problem

Comment: your url loading fine

Comment: as i saw the link, site is loading